# How can I have layouts on a purely static website?

Tags: html, layout, static, amazon-s3

***How do I have slightly dynamic layouts that include HTML files so I only have to write a layout template one time for a static website?***

More specifically, how can I have dynamic layouts on a static website, or one with no server-side code.  I want to redo one of my websites, host it on S3 and write a layout (like below) one time, not have to include it in each page.  The site will have purely information in the form of HTML and PDFs so I don't need any server-side code and am trying to keep it as simple as possible.

```
<html>
  <head>
     ...
  <head>
  <body>
     //each page's content would go here.
  </body>
<html>
```

I have an idea how to do it, but it isn't elegant at all and requires writing a bunch of front-end Javascript, which I don't want to do.  That idea is to create an element on each page and insert it, but this would have to happen in each file, now that I think about it, so it doesn't solve me not wanting to not write a layout for each page at all.

Also, I realize that having a 'dynamic layout' on a 'static website' is oxymoronic; however, I know how smart the StackOverflow community is and how likely there is an acceptable, easy solution to this problem.

If there isn't an easy solution I will have to resort to using a static site generator to build my website but I bet you can come up with one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turns out there is a way!**

*Answering my own question, again.*

**You can write a static site layout one time, without any static site generator or templating language, using only jQuery (you could easily use plain vanilla JS as well) by doing this:**

1. Write your layout/nav etc in index.html or whatever...
2. Create a .js file that will be available to your site by being in every `<head>` in every page you want layouts to be included
3. Put the following in it:

`$(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.location.href.indexOf("index") < 0 ) {
    console.log("Found a file that isn't the home page.");
    $( "#loaded-layout" ).load( "index.html #layout", function() {
      console.log("Should have loaded the layout."); // Callback optional here...
    });
  }
});`

- `index.html #layout` is a div around your header/nav etc in index.html
- `#loaded-layout` is a mandatory div inside every one of your static site's non-index files (`.load` will not run without that div).  It is the div that `#layout` is loaded into

*Boom*.  **You're done**.  No learning another templating engine or any other static site generator conventions.

Now to figure out how to do this with the `<head>`.

**If developing locally without a server (`file:///`) and using Chrome, you must disable web security.  With Macs, do this in your terminal:**

`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security`

Comment: it's true.  A different site for a company I work for uses a purely JS framework, Meteor, so for there the visitors won't get a single character without JS.  Will look for non-JS visitor stats. EDIT: [2% of U.S. _Yahoo_ users four years ago had JS disabled](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydnfourblog/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html).  I'd argue it will be lower for _non-Yahoo_ U.S. users four years later.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is an inclusion mechanism for HTML, similar to [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

If you really don't want any scripting, then a [static site generator](http://staticsitegenerators.net/) should do. I've never used one, but the idea is you write your content in a sort of IDE for websites, then the generator dumps the HTML, which you're never supposed to touch directly.